# Import TXT to Excel (VBA) Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to open a text file and copy and paste it into my Data Sheet. However i can't seem to make it work (I see an object required error). Any help please? Thank you

```
Sub Bam2()
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet, sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook, targetWorkbook As Workbook
Set targetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
Set targetSheet = targetWorkboook.Sheets("Data")
targetSheet.Range("A1:M5000").ClearContents
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Text Files to Open")
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen, Format:=4)
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy

    targetSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    wkbTemp.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is the error message?

Comment: Can you try writing     `Dim FilesToOpen As String` and give it a try again?

Comment: @mrCarnivore It is an Object Required Error, but I can't see where it comes from... everything is defined

Comment: @Vitaya now the error is Subscript out of range

Comment: @Rose: "An object required error" is not more specific than you already told us. In which line is which error exactly?

Comment: Can you specify which line is getting highlighted when you get this error?

Comment: It does not show

Answer (score 1):

At a guess

```
     Set targetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
```

If you've just created a workbook it's called Book1 - it's not called Book1.xlsm unless you've actually saved it under that name. Try

```
   Set targetWorkbook = Application.Workbooks("Book1")
```

Comment: Sheets("Data") does actually exist?   Do you get the error before or after the dialog to select the filename shows?

Comment: I get it before the FilesToOpen command. And Yes, I created a new Sheet called Data, so I just don't know

Answer (score 0):

It does work when doing this, but how do I select to copy just one column in a specific range, and not the whole file?

```
Sub Bam()

Dim FilesToOpen
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Text Files to Open")
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen, Format:=4)
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    With newSheet
        .PasteSpecial
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wkbTemp.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Columns(1).Cells.Copy  
or wkbTemp.Sheets(1).range("a1:a200").Copy